.NET framework Entra/Azure AD - get claims roles?
I'm trying to get appRoles in a .NET framework application using OpenIDConnect with OWIN.
The user can authenticate, but I don't get the roles along with the claim. Unsure where I went wrong:
Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)

app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions() With {
    .ClientId = clientId,
    .Authority = authority,
    .PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
    .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications() With {
.SecurityTokenValidated = Function(context)
                              Dim name As String = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("preferred_username").Value
                              context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name, String.Empty))

                              Return Task.FromResult(0)
                          End Function,
      .AuthenticationFailed = Function(context)
                                  Return Task.FromResult(0)
                              End Function
      }
})


app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate)

End Sub


I believe roles are determined by scope in Entra ID. Did you add a scope based on the application you're trying to connect to (and have Application Permissions/Roles for)?
